# Working with specific subsets of data in an array

Tags: arrays, r, loops

I have an 3D array.

```
dim[Ad]
[1] 144 69 60
```

The first two dimensions represent a grid box (144*69). The third dimension represents 60 different ensembles of climate model output.

I want to create a loop with extracts the first ensemble from the third dimension and apply a function to and so on for each subsequent ensemble.

Comment: Please give a reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
( arr <- array(rep(c(1,2,3), each=4), dim=c(2,2,3)) )
# , , 1
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    1
# [2,]    1    1
# 
# , , 2
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    2    2
# [2,]    2    2
# 
# , , 3
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    3    3
# [2,]    3    3
```

you could e.g.

```
# sum values for ,,1 ,,2 & ,,3 each: 
apply(arr, 3, sum)
# [1]  4  8 12

# or: show unique values for each: 
apply(arr[,,2:3], 3, function(x) unique(as.vector(x)) )
# [1] 2 3
```